# Cardinality of a subset of $A$ without elements $x = 2y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given set $A = \{1, 2, 3, ..., 256\}$, find the cardinality of the biggest subset $A'$ of $A$ such that elements $x, y$ of the form $x = 2y$ do not belong to $A'$

**Attempt**

Split $A$ into odd and even integers.

$128$ odd integers belong in $A'$. Even integers which are divisible by $2$ but not by $4$ are out.

Then take $32$ integers divisible by $4$ but not by $8$. They belong in $A'$. Those divisible by $8$ but not by $16$ are out.

Same with $8$ integers divisible by $16$ but not by $32$

Same with $2$ integers divisible by $64$ but not by $128$

Same with $1$ integer divisible by $256$

Answer: $128 + 32 + 8 + 2 + 1 = 171$.

**How do I prove formally this is indeed the max cardinality?**

Comment: Use pigeon hole.  It's kind of messy but if you have 172 or more you must have at least $44$ evens and $44$ odds and at most $20$ of you evens are of the form $2*odd$ but as... it's basically the same argument as you did to make the set if you try to chose any less of one time an more of the other you cut your resource pool too tight.  Or you could put this in binary and get that if a number ends with 0 you can't have the number with the 0 lopped off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let: 
$$A_1 = \{129,130,...,256\} \implies |A_1| =128$$
$$A_2 = \{33,34...,64\} \implies |A_2| =32$$
$$A_3 = \{9,10,...,16\} \implies |A_3| =8$$
$$A_4 = \{1,3,4\} \implies |A_4| =3$$

---

Let $$B_1 = \{65,66,...,128\} $$
$$B_2 = \{17,18,....,32\} $$
$$B_3 = \{5,6,7,8\} $$
$$B_4 = \{2\} $$
and let $C_i = A_i \cup B_i$.

**Lemma:** From set $C_1$ we can take at most 128 elements in $A'$.

Proof: Since we have 64 pairs $(64+i,128+2i)$ for $i=1,..64$, we can take at most one element from each pair in $A'$ so we have at most 64 elements form that pairs in $A'$ and we have at most 64 elements which are left in $C_1$. So we can take at most 128 elements form $C_1$ in to $A'$.

Simillary lemma we can do for other $C_i$...

So $|A'|\leq 171$ and this number is achieved with following example:
 $$A' = A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4$$

Comment: The specific $A'$ would be the very set I thus constructed:
all odd integers; all integers divisible by 4 but not by 8 and so on. Question is - how do I prove this **is** the upper bound?

Comment: "You have to find a concrete A′".. Um, the OP did and said so in the very beginning.  "For now you have only upper bound."... Um, no he doesn't.  That's the entire point of the question.  How does he know $171$ is an upper bound?

Comment: @fleablood Have you read my edit? Um?

Comment: No, I had not.  That edit is fairly nice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the partition
$$A = \{ 1, 2 \} \cup \{ 3, 6 \} \cup \{ 4, 8 \} \cup \{ 5, 10 \} \cup \cdots \cup \{ 127, 254 \} \cup \{ 129 \} \cup \{ 131 \} \cup \cdots \cup \{ 255 \} \cup \{ 256 \}.$$
More explicitly,
$$A = \left(\bigcup_{1 \le n < 128, 2 \mid \operatorname{ord}_2(n)} \{ n, 2n \}\right) \cup \left(\bigcup_{128 < n \le 256, 2 \mid \operatorname{ord}_2(n)} \{ n \} \right).$$
Now, any set $A'$ satisfying the required condition can have at most one element in common with each part of this partition.  However, the partition has exactly 171 parts - which can easily be seen from the fact that your candidate $A'$ has exactly one element in each part of the partition.